# mex file error const input prhs changes after mex is called

Tags: matlab, mex

I'm working on a Matlab code that takes video frames, puts them inside a cell array such as

```
frames{fr} = read(videoObj, fr);
```

For a sample video, I check the frames cell, and it contains 84 frames (video has 84 frames), and all cells are full with images.

I have a mex file, as standard, it is such as

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
```

As I have read the properties of mex file creation, they say input `prhs` is `const mxArray` so that whatever happens inside the mex code, input does not change. I give the matlab's frames cell array as input to mex file as `prhs[0]` is the frames cell and I do some processing (I swear I don't change what I take in `prhs[0]`). However as I debug the Matlab code, I see that right after I call the mex file (and give frames to the mex file as input), last cell of my frames cell seems to be deleted. When I look at 84th cell, it is `[]`, and sometimes it is a random number such as 8 or 4. I don't understand how or why my frames cell's last column disappears when I call mex file.

You may think I might have an error in my Matlab code but when I debug, I looked at frames right before the mex is processed, it has 84 cells and last cell is an image as expected, but right after I call the mex, frames is still 84 cells but last cell is `[]` : empty.

I will appreciate if anyone can help me, why would such as thing happen? Does `const mxArray` not mean 'input will not be changed in the mex' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The `const mxArray* prhs[]` covers the **pointer** to the `mxArray[]` only. It turns out that it is possible (though **highly risky**) to change the values of the input arguments inside the `mexFunction`.
2. Another point worth noting is that although arrays and cells in matlab are indexed from `1..n`, in `C/C++` (and especially in `mex` files) elements are indexed from **0**,...,**n-1**.  So the fact that in debugger you see that `cell[84]` is empty (or has a random value in it) is because you are accessing **beyond the end of the cell array**!